# Build requirements and Runtime requirements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Can any body tell my what is the deference between Build and runtime requirements I'm reading apple documentation and in the source code appear

```
Build Requirements: 
iOS 4.3 or later
Runtime Requirements:   
iOS 4.0 or later. iPhone 4, iPad 2 Wifi + 3G or later.
```

I not found information about that.
If this is a bad question let my now why I'm newbie.

Comment: I never heard of *build requirements* for deployment targeting platform. It should be iOS SDK, not the iOS itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Build Requirements** means the minimum iOS version need to build that specific method or feature.

**Runtime Requirements** means the needed iOS version for installing the application with that particular method or feature.

Check this [**link**](http://www.scribd.com/doc/55726529/1/Understanding-the-iOS-Runtime-Environment#outer_page_13) for more such terms